# How to use Nusoap in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, nusoap

I am new in nusop , I have a code which works good in php simple file ( I mean not in laravel ) , but when I want to use it in laravel ,does not work at all !

this is my code :

```
<?php

require_once "./lib/nusoap.php";
//Parameters    
//
 
$param  =   array(
                'user_id'   =>  'MY_USERNAME',
                'password'  =>  'MY_PASSWORD',
                'lic_username'  =>  '.......',
                'lic_password'  =>  '.......',
                'debug' =>1);


//Create    object  that    referer a   web services    


$client =   new nusoap_client('https://store.esetme.com/remote/v2/webshop.php?wsdl' ,true);



//Call  a   function    at  server  and send    parameters  too 
$response   = $client->call("GetLicenseVerification", $param);
//Process   result  
//


if  ($client->fault)    {
                echo    "FAULT: <p>Code:    ("  .   $client->faultcode  .   "</p>";
                echo    "String:    "   .   $client->faultstring;
}   else    {
                
                if  ($response['error'] ==  '') {
                                //Request   is  Successful
                                //Handle    Response    Data
                                echo    $response['licensekey'];
                                echo    '<br    />';
                                echo    $response['username'];
                                echo    '<br    />';
                                echo    $response['password'];
            
                                echo    '<br    />';
                                echo    $response['expiration_date'];
                }
                else    {
                                //An    error   occurred
                                //Handle    Error
                                echo    $response['error'];
                }
                
                
}
?>
```

> and the output is : test-licensekey test-username test-password
> 09/29/2015

But I want to use it in Laravel 5.1  .

so I created `Libraries` directory in `app` Folder , and put `nusoap.php` there and renamed it to `nusoap_client.php` and I have put namespace `App\Libraries;`  in top of it .
and I use this in my controller , but out put is null !

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Libraries\nusoap_client;
class NusoapController extends Controller
{

    public function getIndex()
    {
            $param  =   array(
                'user_id'   =>  'MY_USERNAME',
                'password'  =>  'MY_PASSWORD',
                'lic_username'  =>  '.......',
                'lic_password'  =>  '.......',
                'debug' =>1);

//Create    object  that    referer a   web services


        $client =   new nusoap_client('https://store.esetme.com/remote/v2/webshop.php?wsdl' ,true);



//Call  a   function    at  server  and send    parameters  too
        $response   = $client->call("GetLicenseVerification", $param);
//Process   result
//


        if  ($client->fault)    {
            echo    "FAULT: <p>Code:    ("  .   $client->faultcode  .   "</p>";
            echo    "String:    "   .   $client->faultstring;
        }   else    {

            if  ($response['error'] ==  '') {
                //Request   is  Successful
                //Handle    Response    Data
                echo    $response['licensekey'];
                echo    '<br    />';
                echo    $response['username'];
                echo    '<br    />';
                echo    $response['password'];

                echo    '<br    />';
                echo    $response['expiration_date'];
            }
            else    {
                //An    error   occurred
                //Handle    Error
                echo    $response['error'];
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution  , I changed my idea for using nusoap library ! 
I decided to use pure soap :

this is my controller which works good :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use SoapClient;
class NusoapController extends Controller
{

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $client = new SoapClient('https://store.esetme.com/remote/v2/webshop.php?wsdl');
        $results = $client->GetLicenseVerification( 'MY_USERNAME' , 'MY_PASSS' , '......' , '......' , 1 );

        print_r($results);
    }

}
```